# jQuery animate not working on hover

Tags: jquery, css, hover, jquery-animate

Pulling my hair out over this, seems simple but for whatever reason isn't working.

I'm trying to animate a div container within an element when you hover over the parent element using jquery.

The idea is, when you hover over the parent, the child div slides down, and when you hover out it moves back to it's original position.

Here is my html markup:

```
<article class="skizzar_masonry_entry " style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">

<a class="skizzar_ma_fancybox clickable" href="http://www.skizzar.com/paulthefunkydrummer/files/2015/01/paul_jones_drummer_gallery_16-683x1024.jpg">
    <i class="skizzar_ma_overlay fa fa-search" style="top: 0px;"></i>
    <img alt="Paul Jones" src="http://www.skizzar.com/paulthefunkydrummer/files/2015/01/paul_jones_drummer_gallery_16-683x1024.jpg"></img>
</a>

</article>
```

and my jQuery:

```
$(".skizzar_masonry_entry").hover(function(){
$('.skizzar_ma_overlay', this).animate({'top': '100px'}, 400, 'easeOutExpo');
}, function(){
$('.skizzar_ma_overlay', this).animate({'top': '0'}, 400, 'easeOutExpo');
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle showing my work:
http://jsfiddle.net/h3sqe9re/

Comment: Is `easeOutExpo` an existing easing function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include jQuery-UI for custom transitions. `easeOutExpo` isn't included in jQuery core library.

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h3sqe9re/5/)

> **Easing**
>
> The remaining parameter of .animate() is a string naming an easing function to use. An easing function specifies the speed at which the animation progresses at different points within the animation. The only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default, called swing, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called linear. More easing functions are available with the use of plug-ins, most notably the [jQuery UI suite](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/).

Comment: ah yes, I hadn't seen that! needed a fresh pair of eyes  -thanks!

Comment: @SamSkirrow You missed Black-Friday to buy new ones :P

Answer (score 0):

If you check your console, you will see an error that `undefined is not a function` at `jQuery.easing[ this.easing ]()`.

Basically the easing method you have defined `easeOutExpo` is not available in the core jQuery library - it is part of jQuery UI.

Adding jQuery UI (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js) to your fiddle makes this work

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3sqe9re/8/)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't require js at all. I used `css` to make hover effect.

Set the fixed height for the **hidden** div then remove that height, while hovering on the top most of the div. (i.e Hovering on the whole div) .

http://jsfiddle.net/simeon1929/h3sqe9re/14/